# Responsive design displaying div during wrong media query

Tags: html, css

I'm just playing around with responsive design and put together the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="mobile">Mobile</div>
<div id="tablet">Tablet</div>
<div id="desktop">Desktop</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width:800px){
     #mobile{
         display:hidden;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:hidden;
     }
     #desktop{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:green;
     }
 }
 @media (min-width:500px) and (max-width:799px){
     #desktop{
         display:hidden;
     }
     #tablet{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:black;
         color:white;
     }
     #mobile{
         display:hidden;
     }
 }

 @media (max-width:499px){
     #desktop{
         display:hidden;
     }
     #mobile{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:blue;
         color:white;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:hidden;
     }
 }
```

What happens is that the text Mobile Tablet and Desktop shows at all times and according to the CSS, the background colour and formatting changes as they should.

If I'm hiding the div when the media query width doesn't match, why is the text within the div still showing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display:hidden` doesn't exist, it's `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Ha no worries, it happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/zZE6W/

CSS

```
@media (min-width:800px){
     #mobile{
         display:none;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:none;
     }
     #desktop{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:green;
     }
 }
 @media (min-width:500px) and (max-width:799px){
     #desktop{
         display:none;
     }
     #tablet{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:black;
         color:white;
     }
     #mobile{
         display:none;
     }
 }

 @media (max-width:499px){
     #desktop{
         display:none;
     }
     #mobile{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:blue;
         color:white;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:none;
     }
 }
```